# Not able to start Hbase shell in standalone mode

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I installed hbase on my ubuntu 64-bit system. I could run hbase start script without any issues and below is the result.

```
hduser@vignesh-ubuntu:/usr/local/hbase$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-master-vignesh-ubuntu.out
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
```

But when i start my hbase shell it throws me below error.

```
hduser@vignesh-ubuntu:/usr/local/hbase$ ./bin/hbase shell
NativeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  initialize at /usr/local/hbase/bin/../lib/ruby/hbase/hbase.rb:42
      (root) at /usr/local/hbase/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:118
```

The JDK version i am using is 1.8. Path: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_31

I tried googling but no luck. Could some one help me in resolving this.

Comment: HBase is still not supported on java 1.8 officially. can you try with java1.7?

Answer (score 0):

It look like compile version different with runtime java version.

You'd best look at [HBase java version help](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#java).